# Jquery DataTables - column filtering with multiple elements in td

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Using jquery datatables I want to filter a column which can contain multiple values in a single td.

I followed the datables [link](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)

In below picture I want to filter the office column and as you can see **one** td contains**strong text** two values: "**Edinburgh**" and "**New York**".
Even though the names appear in the filter they **don't return** a value once selected. For the single elements it is working fine.

So in below example my expected result would be to filter for New York and have a single row returned (including the text of "Edinburgh").

[image: sample]

I've created a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ad4o2d55/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        initComplete: function () {
  this.api().columns('.dt-filter').every(function () {
var column = this;
var select = $('<select class="form-control" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="max-width:200px"><option></option></select>')
    .appendTo($("#filters").find("th").eq(column.index()))
  .on('change', function () {
  var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
  $(this).val());
  column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();});

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
        if (d.indexOf("<p>") >= 0) {
                            var b = d;
                                $(b).each(function (index) {
                        var text = $(this).text();
                    select.append('<option value="' + text.trim() + '">' + text.trim() + '</option>')
                    });
                }
                  .....
```

Is it possible to have multiple values in one column in order to filter by a value?

BTW I just use the p-Element for testing, I don't mind the "li" element or something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();});`, 
just use `column.search(val).draw();});`

Should search you table rows with multiple strings.

So the overall code becomes as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable({
initComplete: function() {
  this.api().columns('.dt-filter').every(function() {
    var column = this;
    var select = $('<select class="form-control" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="max-width:200px"><option></option></select>')
      .appendTo($("#filters").find("th").eq(column.index()))
      .on('change', function() {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
          $(this).val());
        column.search(val).draw();
      });

    column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
      if (d.indexOf("<p>") >= 0) {
        var b = d;
        $(b).each(function(index) {
          var text = $(this).text();
          select.append('<option value="' + text.trim() + '">' + text.trim() + '</option>')
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To do exact match of one column against multiple criteria, I would recommend external search plugin [`$.fn.DataTable.ext.search`](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search#Plug-in-structure).

That is array where you may push your custom function that iterates over table rows and should return `true` if the row is matching your criteria (supplied from external variable) and `false` otherwise.

In general this logic is implemented by [this](https://github.com/ygorbunkov/datatables-multiple-criteria-filter) DataTable plug-in. It solves your exact problem, though data-specific processing of other datatypes (numbers, dates) is yet to come.

Your given example may look like:

```js
var srcData = [
  {name: 'Bruce Wayne', office: 'Gotham', position: 'CEO'},
  {name: 'Clark Kent', office: 'Metropolis', position: 'Journalist'},
  {name: 'Arthur Curry', office: 'Atlantis', position: 'Diver'},
  {name: 'Barry Allen', office: 'Central City', position: 'Forensics expert'},
  {name: 'Diana Prince', office: 'Themyscira', position: 'Art Consultant'}
];

$('#mytable').DataTable({
  sDom: 'tF',
  data: srcData,
  columns: [
    {title: 'Name', data: 'name'},
    {title: 'Office', data: 'office'},
    {title: 'Position', data: 'position'},
  ]
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.mfilter.tk/js/mfilter.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.mfilter.tk/css/mfilter.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
```